# Finding an elusive parasitic draw......?

Tags: starting, chevrolet, battery-drain

This has been bothering me for a year now! Once a month I would go and start my car and it would hesitate to start and I would hold the key on start until it starts all the way up. Battery is good, alternator was tested and was normal and starter is fine. It's rare that it happens but it does make me wonder.

I tested it one time when I turned it off while it was starting (hesitating) and turned it back on and it died completely

Comment: The title doesn't really seem to be elaborated upon in the question... What exactly are you asking us?

Comment: Just asking where else I should check for what could cause the engine to hesitate when starting

Comment: So many things...

Comment: What do you mean you tested it? Have you measured the amount of draw? What's the reserve capacity on your battery?

Comment: Have a read through this and see if it helps. There's far too much information to try to reproduce here https://axleaddict.com/auto-repair/car-batterydrain

Comment: how do you know starter is fine?